# How to perform a BETWEEN operator in Hive SQL for date column

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, cloudera, bigdata

I'll try to explain my problem as clear as possible. I would like to filter a table by date (selecting only the record have the date included in **current month**) and in Oracle SQL I'm using the following query to achieve such goal:

```
select * from table t1 
where t1.DATE_COLUMN between TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'mm') and SYSDATE
```

How can I replicate the same filter in Hive SQL? The column I should use to apply the filter is a **TIMESTAMP** type column (e.g. *2017-05-15 00:00:00*).

I'm using CDH 5.7.6-1.

Any advice?

Comment: Is `DATE_COLUMN` a partition column?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz no, it's not a partition column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that `unix_timestamp` is not fixed and is going to change during the query.
For that reason it cannot be used for partitions elimination.
For newer Hive versions use `current_date` / `current_timestamp` instead.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

```
select  * 
from    table t1 
where   t1.DATE_COLUMN  
          between  cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'yyyy-MM-01 00:00:00') as timestamp)
          and      cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()) as timestamp)
;
```

---

```
select  cast (from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'yyyy-MM-01 00:00:00') as timestamp)
       ,cast (from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()) as timestamp)
;
```

---

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
|         _c0         |         _c1         |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2017-05-01 00:00:00 | 2017-05-16 01:04:55 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

You can format as strings:

```
where date_format(t1.DATE_COLUMN, 'y-m') = date_format(current_timestamp, 'y-m')
```

I realize that I don't have Hive accessible right now.  The documentation suggests `'y-m'`, but the Java documentation suggests `'yyyy-mm'`.

Comment: I've tried as you suggested but I get a semantic exception error "Invalid function date_format.